# Qt Release build unable to open DLL

Tags: c++, qt, dll

While my application runs fine and nice in Debug mode of Qt 4.8.1 using QtCreator 2.4.1, it fails to start up in Release mode. Double clicking the generated .exe returns:

"The application was unable to start correctly (0XC000007B). Click okay to close the application."

Running in QtCreator simply stalls (the application window does not appear) and it will eventually returns with error code: -1073741819

Running Dependency Walker will show that:

[image]

I have tried to search the location of msvcr90.dll and it appears in multiple directories under C:/Windows/winsxd/...

What should I do to fix this problem at this point? My machine is 64x Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You should deploy the Qt (and some other) libraries in order to run your application by that way.

The dll files are in the bin folder of your library installation path. For example, in my machine it is:

```
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\bin
```

Because I'm using the MSVC2010 version (instead of the MinGW version) of Qt. Dependency Walker will tell you what files do you have to copy.

Qt Creator should run your application fine. What version of Qt are you using? (4.8, MinGW or VC2010)

Comment: I am using MSVS2010 I believe, since in build it says "Qt 4.8.1 for Desktop MSVS2010(Qt SDK) Debug/Release" for either release or debug build. You mean that I need to copy the dll file into the same folder as my application .exe?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Or you could register them. 
But anyway, when deploying your application, it's easier to just copy those DLLs in the same folder as the executable

Comment: However, I have found multiple copies of the same two DLL, which one would be the correct version? So far, I've managed to guess that it has to do with locality (language).

Comment: Languages do not require separate DLLs (the strings are in .qm files). The SDK contains multiple Qt's as the QtCreator brings its own (to make it independent of the one developed against), and depending on the installation, one might have more Qt versions, e.g. for embedded devices.

Comment: Or maybe you are confusing the debug with the release versions. The debug versions end with d. Ej: QtCored.dll

Comment: So for desktop releases, which DLL should I use?

Comment: If you are not using any extra modules (like QtScript), you should copy QtGui4.dll and QtCore4.dll from C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\bin (supposing your installation directory is QtSDK and your Qt version is 4.8.0)